# Shotwell Photos For Email

Tags: email, shotwell, photo

How do you compress photos in Shotwell prior to attaching them to an email. The average jpeg in Shotwell is over 1 mb far too big for emailing. The help file isn't any use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the photo > send to > choose your format > send as: ? e-mail > choose you type of compression >  zip or tar > Goes to default email application.

Comment: How do I know the recipient will be able to open a zip or tar?

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Regards,

Comment: Neither ZIP nor TAR will reduce the size of a JPEG foto significantly.